# List events API call on Microsoft Graph Java SDK doesn't work for @outlook.com domain

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

When I tried the following GET request using [Microsoft Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=/me/calendars/joseph.baker.doodle@outlook.com/calendarView?startDateTime=2019-10-24T07:40:43.133Z&endDateTime=2019-10-31T07:40:43.133Z&method=GET&version=beta&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com):

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta//me/calendars/joseph.baker.doodle@outlook.com/calendarView?startDateTime=2019-10-24T07:40:43.133Z`

I got this response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidIdMalformed",
        "message": "Id is malformed.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "7ffa9b3c-b5bf-4171-b5ad-242dd831b629",
            "date": "2019-11-21T06:30:12"
        }
    }
}
```

When I try it with user's calendar ID:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta//me/calendars/AQMkADAwATM3ZmYAZS0yNDI1LTEwMmMtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADWt9re56XX0ay-rq-yg7yKwcA94f8IFhbyEuRrCHknQvqSwAAAgEGAAAA94f8IFhbyEuRrCHknQvqSwAAADW523EAAAA=/calendarView?startDateTime=2019-10-24T07:40:43.133Z&endDateTime=2019-10-31T07:40:43.133Z`

Also for an account with `@onmicrosoft.com`:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta//me/calendars/joseph.baker.doodle@onmicrosoft.com/calendarView?startDateTime=2019-10-24T07:40:43.133Z`

It works as expected.

Can somebody help me with this? Is the issue domain-related?

Answer (score 0):

Calendars are always referenced by `id` instead of name. Also, since Outlook.com is a single-user platform, it simply isn't possible to reference another user's resources.

I'm frankly surprised `/me/calendars/joseph.baker.doodle@onmicrosoft.com/` since this is not a supported/documented address scheme.

Comment: in the official  documentation [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http] it is stated a user can list events of another user's calendar ```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendar/events``` by their principal name (for my test users these matched their emails) and retrieve what I am guessing is the list of events for the other user's primary calendar , as long as that calendar is shared with the user that is requesting access.

Comment: You can only list events from another user when that user is within the same Office 365 tenant. You cannot list another `@outlook.com` user's calendar for any reason (they are not part of the same tenant).